# Software updates - Avoiding the need to clear cache

Tags: caching, browser, updates, browser-cache

(I'm a project manager, not a developer)
In every web-software project I have ever been involved in, the same problem occurs:

An update changes scripts, CSS etc, but users' browsers have cached the old versions and thus the updates don't work until the user clears cache, (typically be pressing Ctrl-f5). Obviously we inform users that they should clear their caches, but half of them don't, and they complain.

Is there a general way to solve this problem? Or a specific way for certain technologies (We work in various projects in Angular, PHP and dotnet)

Comment: There are several ways. One way would be to add a version number or a timestamp to the scripts. So each time you change them, they'll get a new version and they will be loaded from scratch.

Comment: dotnet using IIS, you can restart apppool and the website will be refreshed. in angular when you serve the website it clear the cache(provided you are using nginx)

Comment: @Dunni, Thank you. I suggested this to our devs a whileback and they said it was not possible to do in an automated way. Are you aware of any tools to help with it?

Comment: @JackM, thanks to you as well. Our current angular (Angular 1) project is hosted on Heroku and it does not seem to do this. If you or anybody else is aware of a way to force it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @AndrewSit: Herokou is just a platform and when you add new css these should be picked up even if you have node running. but for benefit of doubt you can just restart node to make sure that the app is started. I have also found that chrome tend to be the one causing caching issues

Comment: We solved this by adding a hash of the file to the name of the file, thus, if the content changes, the file name is updated. Works perfectly